# Autoindent uses tabs after paste mode

Tags: indentation

My `.vimrc`:

```
:set tabstop=2
:set shiftwidth=2
:set ai
:set expandtab
```

My workflow:

- vi `filename`
- type `space` `space`text`enter`, cursor is now under 't', indented with 2 spaces.  As expected.
- `:set paste`
- paste block of text that is indented using spaces, pasted as expected
- `:set ai` (to go back to auto indenting)
- type `space` `space`text`enter`, cursor is now under 't', indented with 1 tab.  I expected this would be indented with spaces.

Where am I going wrong?  I've used this `.vimrc` setup in the past and it's worked normally.  Not really sure where it's going wrong.

Using: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 27 2022 06:12:50)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Why are you using `:set ai` instead of `:set nopaste` to undo the effects of `'paste'` mode? I think that might be related to your issue. Do you still reproduce if you use `:set nopaste` in that step instead?

Comment: If you look at [`:help 'paste'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) you'll see that it resets quite a few options, including `'expandtab'`, so maybe that's what's happening here?

Comment: @filbranden `:set nopaste` works in the expected manner.  I've always used `:set ai` and it worked the way I wanted before.  Very strange.  Not sure what was different.  Thanks.  I'll just have to remember `:set nopaste` in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is due to the [`'paste'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) option having an effect on a series of other options and not simply disabling auto-indent. (See `:help 'paste'` for a list of all options that are affected by it.)

When you try to undo it by simply running `:set ai`, you're still leaving behind most of the other side-effects, in particular `'expandtab'` having been reset, which probably explains why you're seeing this specific side-effect of getting automatic indentation with tabs instead of spaces.

In order to prevent this issue, use `:set nopaste` instead of `:set ai` to disable paste mode.

---

You might want to consider adopting the [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plug-in, which includes a few commands (`]op`, `[op` and `yop`) to start insert in `'paste'` mode and automatically leave `'paste'` mode once you leave insert mode, so you don't need to use an explicit command to leave `'paste'` mode.

I also add an Insert mode binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to start `'paste'` mode from Insert mode:

```
inoremap <C-e> <C-g>u<C-o>:execute "normal \<Plug>unimpairedPaste"<cr>
```

(Note that the above mapping depends on the vim-unimpaired plug-in being available. The [`<C-g>u`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-G_u) at the beginning breaks the undo sequence, so that if you use `u` to undo after a paste it will only undo the paste itself and not what you inserted while in Insert mode before pasting.)

---

If you prefer not to load a Vim plug-in, you can accomplish something similar to the part of disabling `'paste'` at the end of an Insert with an `autocmd` for the [`InsertLeave`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#InsertLeave) event:

```
augroup Paste
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertLeave * set nopaste
augroup END
```

The above will execute a `:set nopaste` every time you leave Insert mode.

You can also use the [`'pastetoggle'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27pastetoggle%27) option to set a hotkey to enter or leave `'paste'` mode from Insert mode. For example:

```
set pastetoggle=<C-e>
```

But personally I prefer the `inoremap` mentioned above, because typically I prefer to leave Insert mode and have the `autocmd` disable paste mode rather than switch it on and off while staying in Insert mode. Additionally, I like the feature of the mapping that breaks the undo sequence. So for those reasons I typically end up avoiding `'pastetoggle'`, but it might work well for you.

Comment: Don’t forget pastetoggle ;)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer!  Just tried the autocmd, and it works brilliantly.